# Constrained optimization in python where one variable depends on another variable

Tags: python, linear-programming, constraint-programming

I have a problem where I have 4 variables `x1, x2, x3 and x4`. I need to find the values for `x1, x2, x3, x4` with the following conditions:

```
1. 1995 < 2*x1 + 4*x2 + 3*x3 + x4 < 2000
2. x1 >= 1.2*x2
3. x2 >= 1.3*x3
4. x3 >= 1.1*x4
5. x4 > 0.0
```

I was able do this using python-constraint (https://labix.org/python-constraint) but it takes ~30 mins to solve this on my system, which is too long.

```
from constraint import *

problem = Problem()
problem.addVariable("x1", range(100,500))
problem.addVariable("x2", range(100,500))
problem.addVariable("x3", range(100,500))
problem.addVariable("x4", range(100,500))

problem.addConstraint(lambda a, b, c, d: 2*a + 3*b + 4*c + 5*d > 1995, ["x1", "x2", "x3", "x4"])
problem.addConstraint(lambda a, b, c, d: 2*a + 3*b + 4*c + 5*d < 2005, ["x1", "x2", "x3", "x4"])
problem.addConstraint(lambda a, b: a >= 1.2 * b, ["x1", "x2"])
problem.addConstraint(lambda b, c: b >= 1.3 * c, ["x2", "x3"])
problem.addConstraint(lambda c, d: c >= 1.1 * d, ["x3", "x4"])
problem.addConstraint(lambda d: d > 0, ["x4"])

problem.getSolutions()
```

I also looked at `scipy.optimize.linprog` but I could not find a way to pass conditions 2, 3 and 4 because it is dependent on the value of another variable from the same problem. I can pass boundaries for each individual variables using the `bounds` parameter, like:

```
x1_bounds = (100, 200)
x2_bounds = (200, 300)
```

But how do I pass values of other variables in bounds, like `x1_bounds >= 1.2*x2`? Or is there any other way I can do this?

This can be solved using GRG non-linear solver in excel but I'm not able to find an equivalent in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is, in fact, linear, and so it's ideally suited to a linear programming approach.  However, you are giving it to the solver with no clues as to the linearity of the problem, so it's bound to find that tricky: it pretty much has to try every possibility which is going to take a long time.  It might be possible to rewrite your constraints into different forms for the `python-constraint` solver (it has, for example, a `MaxSumConstraint` constraint form) which might work better but ideally I think you should be using a solver specialised for linear problems.

There is a solver called `kiwisolver` which will do what you want.  Here's your example converted for that library:

```
import kiwisolver

x1 = kiwisolver.Variable('x1')
x2 = kiwisolver.Variable('x2')
x3 = kiwisolver.Variable('x3')
x4 = kiwisolver.Variable('x4')

constraints = [1995 <= 2*x1 + 4*x2 + 3*x3 + x4,
               2*x1 + 4*x2 + 3*x3 + x4 <= 2000,
               x1 >= 1.2*x2,
               x2 >= 1.3*x3,
               x3 >= 1.1*x4,
               x4 >= 0]

solver = kiwisolver.Solver()

for cn in constraints:
    solver.addConstraint(cn)

for x in [x1, x2, x3, x4]:
    print(x.value())
```

which gives

```
254.49152542372883
212.07627118644066
163.13559322033896
148.30508474576254
```

But you can also use a standard linear program solver like the scipy one. You just need to reorganise your inequalities into the right form.

You want:

```
1. 1995 < 2*x1 + 4*x2 + 3*x3 + x4 < 2000
2. x1 >= 1.2*x2
3. x2 >= 1.3*x3
4. x3 >= 1.1*x4
5. x4 > 0.0
```

So we rewrite this into:

```
 2*x1 +  4*x2 +  3*x3 +  1*x4 < 2000
-2*x1 + -4*x2 + -3*x3 + -1*x4 < -1995
-1*x1 + 1.2*x2 + 0*x3 +  0*x4 < 0
 0*x1 + -1*x2 + 1.3*x3 + 0*x4 < 0
 0*x1 +  0*x2 + -1*x3 + 1.1*x4 < 0
```

You can add bounds for `x1` to `x4` as you mentioned in the question but by default they will just be non-negative.  So then, for an LP, we also need to choose where in the polytope of possible solutions we want to optimise: in this case I'll just go for the solution with the minimum sum.  So that gives us this:

```
from scipy.optimize import linprog

output = linprog([1, 1, 1, 1],
                [[ 2,   4,   3,   1],
                 [-2,  -4,  -3,  -1],
                 [-1, 1.2,   0,   0],
                 [0,   -1, 1.3,   0],
                 [0,    0,  -1, 1.1]],
                [2000, -1995, 0, 0, 0])

print(output.x)
```

This gives

```
[274.92932862 229.10777385 176.23674912   0.        ]
```

which is the optimal LP solution.  Note that it has made `x4 = 0`: LPs typically don't distinguish between `>` and `>=` and so we have a solution where `x4` is zero rather than a tiny epsilon greater than zero.

Finally, note that the problem is strongly under-constrained: we can choose a quite different solution by changing the objective.  Here's a solution where we ask `linprog` to maximise `2*x1 + 4*x2 + 3*x3 + x4`:

```
from scipy.optimize import linprog


output = linprog([-2, -4, -3, -1],
                 [[ 2,   4,   3,  1],
                  [-2,  -4,  -3, -1],
                  [-1, 1.2,   0, 0],
                  [0,   -1, 1.3, 0],
                  [0,    0,  -1, 1.1]],
                 [2000, -1995, 0, 0, 0])

print(output.x)
```

giving

```
[255.1293488  212.60779066 163.54445436 148.67677669]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Re-writing the constraints as equations is what I should've done.

Comment: @ananthbv I have added a version using the kiwisolver package which is specifically written for constraint systems like yours.

Comment: thanks once again. I will look into kiwisolver as well. Is there a way to use constants in the function to be minimized, ex: Minimize ```2*x1 + 4*x2 +3*x3 +x4 - 2000```

Comment: No - because it wouldn't have any effect - adding the constant doesn't change the optimising values of ``x1`` to ``x4``.

Comment: Got it. But, when I run the second code with linprog to maximise ```2*x1 + 4*x2 + 3*x3 + x4```, I'm getting the solution ```[375.  312.5   0.    0. ]```, and not ```[255.1293488  212.60779066 163.54445436 148.67677669]```. Any suggestions why?

Comment: Yes - the program MINIMISES the objective.  So you need to make it negative to maximise.

Comment: Yes, but when I run the code, I'm not getting the same result that you got when I run the linprog code to maximise: ```[255.1293488 212.60779066 163.54445436 148.67677669]```. Instead, I got ```[375. 312.5 0. 0. ]```. Any suggestions why?

Comment: I can only suggest that you are not copying my code verbatim.  I get your result if I replace the objective with [-2, -4, 1, 1].